# PHP Force Download Help

Tags: php, hyperlink, download, anchor

I've been wrestling around with this for awhile now. I am trying to make it so when a user click a link it will force a download. Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
function Download()
{
    $fullpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."front.dwg"; //Full path of document
$filename = "front.dwg";  //Document file nmae


  $mm_type="application/octet-stream";

    header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: hack");
    header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
    header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($fullpath)) );
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
}
?>

<html>
<body>

<a href="#" onclick="<?php Download() ?>">Test</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, how did you do that, I tried that and it showed up all funny

Comment: You've been here for two months, and asked 49 questions. Please learn to use properly use the editor.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, there is a "code" button on the toolbar when you are posting.  Just highlight code and click it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your going to need to pull out your function and save it as "download.php"

Then just have a link that goes to it:

```
<a href="download.php">
```

Download.php should look like this:

```
$fullpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."front.dwg"; //Full path of document
$filename = "front.dwg";  //Document file nmae


 $mm_type="application/octet-stream";

   header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
   header("Pragma: hack");
   header("Content-Type: " . $mm_type);
   header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($fullpath)) );
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
```

Comment: I don't want it to take them anywhere off my page though

Comment: @Howdy, you don't have to...  You can link to the same page, and just check if a variable was set, like `$_GET['do_download']`.

Comment: The file should be downloaded when the user clicks due to the content-disposition, the user won't leave the current page

Comment: That worked. Why did it not go to "download.php" before downloading the file though? I'm having this problem in other scripting im doing too.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, it *did* go to download.php.  You just gave it a suggested file name, that's all.

Comment: Because the alterations of the headers makes the browser realize that the page that the user is going to isn't a website, it's a file, so it thinks the best thing to do is download it instead of trying to traverse it

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: Please read and understand [this section](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_PHP#How_Does_PHP_Work.3F) of Techtopia's PHP overview. It does a pretty good job of explaining how PHP works, and hopefully it will help you better understand what's going on between your web server and your browser.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not a client-side function.  You can't say `onclick="somePHP"`.

You need a separate PHP script where you will force your download in, and simply link to that script.

In this script, you also need to actually output the file contents.

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time a PHP "problem" was solved by explaining the difference between client-side and server-side code, I'd be driving a better car.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Justin, it's not just PHP.  I think the biggest reason people have trouble getting started with programming is understanding what all the layers are and what to use for what, and how they actually interrelate.  This is especially true in web where a single project can require knowledge of 8 distinctly separate technologies.

Comment: @user828584, I don't see how this is not an answer.  I told him exactly what to do to fix his problem.

Comment: @Brad: True, but PHP is the teething ring of the programming world. I would suggest that more PHP tutorials (or even the manual) state the difference between client and server code more assertively... but the cynical side of me knows that most beginners will skip right over it to get to the delicious copypasta. Sorry to hijack your thread with what amounts to a silly rant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the appropriate calls to [`header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) first. These have worked for me:

```
header('Pragma: public'); // required
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private', false);
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$filename}\"");
header("Content-Type: {$mime}"); // also works with file extension
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can never FORCE a download. You can change the window location to the download file and it will prompt them, but if you could force downloads, there would be some major security issues.

Comment: I don't think he is trying to force a file onto the client's hard drive, he is trying to force the dialog box for a download, vs. displaying it in the browser.

Comment: I can't even display this kind of file in a browser :(

Answer (score 0):

First, your `$fullpath` may not contain the data you expect, because you did not insert a forward slash ('/') before the filename. This is correct:

```
$fullpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/front.dwg";
```

You can check the contents of `$fullpath` using `error_log( "Fullpath: $fullpath" );` or `echo "Fullpath: $fullpath\n"`.

Second, you need to make the PHP portion of your code a standalone script. You will not be able to embed PHP function calls in Javascript. All of your PHP executes before the Javascript runs, so you need a way to call the PHP separately.

Third, you should verify that the file exists and is readable using `file_exists()` and `is_readable()`. If PHP reports that the file does not exists, you should specify the full path. If it is not readable, you can change the file permissions to allow your PHP script to read it.