# Cant figure how to implement following jQuery plugin into my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I've been looking for something that will authorize a textbox when user types something and I found this ideal plugin:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

It seems prety straight forward, but for some reason I can't implement it on my website >.< do you guys have any ideas on how to do it? (read the post)
Thank You )))

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work

**HTML**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/autoresize.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('textarea.mainStatusTxt').autoResize({
// On resize:
onResize : function() {
$(this).css({opacity:0.8});
},
// After resize:
animateCallback : function() {
$(this).css({opacity:1});
},
// Quite slow animation:
animateDuration : 300,
// More extra space:
extraSpace : 40
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea class="mainStatusTxt" placeholder="Comment" style="display:block;"></textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: you may need to place that javascript in a [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) block. It's probably running the js before your textarea is rendered to the dom.

Comment: js is not my strong side, do you mean I should change it to something like $('textarea.mainStatusTxt').ready ... or will it look different?

Comment: place your code inside the `$(document).ready(function() {...});` function, as Justin answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either wrap your script with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //YOUR CODE
});
```

or move the entire `<script>` tag to the end of the document (or at least, after the `<textarea>`).

Comment: In the last 5 days I've seen this as the correct answer about 10 times. Must be time to turn those Web Development 101 projects :)

Comment: Hehe, **HomeworkHelper**, the new site coming to Stack Exchange :)

Comment: If only more people understood how client-side scripting works... [Déjà vu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083890/php-force-download-help/7083924#comment-8479075)